# meaning of the word "enter" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here it goes:

> But what about when you are in public and there isn't a bathroom around? **Enter** the chemical toilet also known as the porta-potty.

I have looked up all the meaning of the word, but still cannot get how someone can enter something.

Comment: It is analogous to *voilà*  in function.  It is like a cue for the chemical toilet to come on stage.

Comment: Either "go into" (a porta-potty is free-standing and has a door) or "introduce", depending on context.

Comment: Similar to first comment: "the chemical toilet has been invented". But the question needs more context.

Comment: Enter used like that comes from the theater: Enter x stage left, enter y stage right.

Comment: But why not enters? The porta potty enters is grammatically correct I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from stage directions, which were brief - probably because they were originally copied out by hand and people wanted to save effort and paper:

> Enter Hamlet
>
> Enter Bob, stage left

It's a direction in a play to say that a character comes onto the stage. It is used idiomatically and metaphorically to talk about something entering the discussion, with the stage being conceptual and metaphorical.